# I've been trying to create a video from numpy arrays using OpenCv. It gives a "corrupted" file most of the time

Tags: python, opencv, video, video-codecs

For some reason some resolutions work and others don't. Many codec-container combinations work but some don't. I know not all containers work with all codecs but it seems weird.

The code below is a version with the same behavior.

```
import cv2
import numpy
import os

os.chdir(os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop"))
shape = (640, 480)
frame = numpy.zeros(tuple([*shape] + [3]), numpy.uint8)

video_name = 'output.avi'
fps = 60
video = cv2.VideoWriter(video_name, cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID'), fps, shape)

for i in range(fps * 5):
    video.write(frame)

video.release()
```

Answer (score 0):

Opencv works (height, width) while numpy (width, height) when defining the shape.
so i need to reverse the tuple before using it to define the VideoWriter shape